# How to solve a first order ODE of this type

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a systematic way to solve an ODE of the following structure?

$\ dy/dt = Ay^2 + By + C$

where $\ A, B, C$ are constants.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely separable and so is trivial to solve (by integration).

$$\int\frac{dy}{Ay^2+By+C} = \int dt$$

To solve the LHS, complete the square and solve it to the form of $t = {k_1\arctan\left({k_1x+k_2\over k_3}\right)\over k_3} + k_4$ where $k_1, k_2, k_3$ depend on $A,B,C$, or, if applicable, use partial fractions to get a lograthmic answer.

Comment: If square is in form $$ (k_1x+k_2)^2-k_3^2$$ then there will be no arctan.

Comment: right, thanks for pointing that out.